Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never' in typescript
Consider this class:
 const creditRiskRatingKeys = [
  'applicant_id',
  'is_dirty',
] as const;

const dict = {
  applicant_id: 'test_id',
  is_dirty: true,
}

class CreditRiskRating {
  applicant_id: string = '';
  is_dirty: boolean = false;

  fillQuestionDictionaryToModel() {
    for (const key of creditRiskRatingKeys) {
      this[key] = dict[key]; // Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    }
  }
}

Key is already keyof CreditRiskRating and this is referring to the same class. Then why this[key] = dict[key]; should complain?? What am I missing here?
Playground

fillQuestionDictionaryToModel is also a key of CreditRiskRating, to which a string cannot be assigned.

"Key is already keyof CreditRiskRating" right and this can be one of applicant_id or fillQuestionDictionaryToModel. So, the value you assign to it should be assignable to both of these at the same time.

@VLAZ Thank you. Is there any way to limit CreditRiskRatingKeys only properties not methods? What is the best way of handling it.

@Sjoertjuh thanks. Do you have any solution for this?

@Sjoertjuh updated the question, and seems that is not working in all cases!

The never is there because it's the intersection of all property types (see ms/TS#30769) and it's therefore unsafe to assign anything to a randomly chosen property. The best way to handle this, as written, is to change it to 'test' as never instead of 'test' as any, but that's just sidestepping it. Right now the question is asking about assigning any to never, which is disallowed. You have some underlying use case; could you [edit] to avoid type assertions ("casting") and any so we can see what that use case looks like?

@jcalz thanks for the comment. Actually I have a question dictionary based on the some properties in my class. and want to sync between question dictionary and my properties in  the class.
Will update my question and need to add more dependency to simulate actual use case.
Still not sure why this[key as keyof this] = 'test' as any; is working?

because keyof this is implicitly generic and so TS will not collapse it to never eagerly. But that's probably out of scope; a SO question should be narrow in scope to a particular thing (the underlying use case here, I'd think) and not a bunch of possibly-related things (all the problems you had with various attempts... each one has reasons why it does or does not work, but future readers are unlikely to have attempted the same set of things).

@jcalz make sense. will update the question to make it focus on underlying use case

The updated question no longer makes sense. You're asking for a type-safe way to assign strings to boolean properties. Might as well stop using TypeScript altogether then.

@jcalz now updated the question. Hopefully now should be clear my question. please let me know if it needs more detail

• You're still trying to assign any places. I suggest you stop annotating things and just let TS infer them for you, so we can get to the starting line. I'd say this playground link shows a [mre] of your issue. Could you [edit] to use the text from that? • If so, then I'd say you've run into ms/TS#32693 and ms/TS#58905 and the right approach is shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll answer; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz Yes this is the exact case, would be happy also to get rid of 'any'. Updated the question. Thank you again

Would you mind also not annotating the creditRiskRatingKeys and using as const? That is important, because you really don't want to copy fillQuestionDictionaryToModel itself and TS needs to be aware of it. If you would just copy the text from here into your question that would be useful... if you don't want to do that, please tell me why so I can make sure my answer doesn't depend on something you don't want to do.

@jcalz Yeah sounds good to me having as const

Thanks! I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

You've basically run into microsoft/TypeScript#32693 as well as microsoft/TypeScript#58905.  See those issues for a canonical answer.

An assignment of the form
bar[k] = foo[k]

where Pick<typeof foo, typeof k> is assignable to Pick<typeof bar, typeof k> (using the Pick utility type to say that we only care about the properties of foo and bar which exist at keys of type k) is almost certainly safe.  But TypeScript fails to see this in most circumstances.
The first problem happens when k is of a union type like "applicant_id" | "is_dirty". TypeScript only tracks the type of k, not its identity, so, for all TypeScript knows, you're writing
bar[k2] = foo[k1]

where k2 and k1 are both of the same union type. That wouldn't be safe, so TypeScript complains.  The only way an assignment like that could be safe is if the foo[k1] has a type that works for all possible k2, which would be the intersection of the relevant property types, not the union:
interface Foo {
    a: string,
    b: boolean,
}
interface Bar extends Foo {
    c: Date
}
function f(foo: Foo, bar: Bar, k: keyof Foo) {
    bar[k] = foo[k]; // error!
    //~~~~ <-- Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'.
}

This is the subject of microsoft/TypeScript#32693, and it's a longstanding open issue in TypeScript.
TypeScript only wants to allow an assignment to bar[k] if that value is both a string and a boolean.  There is no such value... in other words, string & boolean is the impossible never type.  That's basically the error you're seeing.

The recommended approach is to switch from union-typed keys to generic keys.  So instead of k being of type MyKeys, you'd have it be of generic type K extends MyKeys.  And if bar and foo are identical types, then that works:
function g<K extends keyof Foo>(bar: Foo, foo: Foo, k: K) {
    bar[k] = foo[k]; // okay, because bar is a Foo
}

But if the two types are distinct, even if they are equivalent everywhere that matters, then you get an error again:
function h<K extends keyof Foo>(bar: Bar, foo: Foo, k: K) {
    bar[k] = foo[k]; // error!
    //~~~~ <-- Property 'c' is missing in type 'Foo' but required in type 'Bar'.
}

This is the subject of microsoft/TypeScript#58905, and it's considered a design limitation of TypeScript.  The workaround is to synthesize your own types for bar and foo such that they are seen as identical. This can happen by just widening them both to the equivalent of Pick types. Since every Bar is also a Foo, we can just widen bar and leave foo alone:
function i<K extends keyof Foo>(bar: Bar, foo: Foo, k: K) {
    const _bar: Foo = bar; // okay
    _bar[k] = foo[k]; // okay
}


So, we need to make things generic, and the object types need to be identical. Doing both with your code looks like:
type CreditRiskRatingKey = typeof creditRiskRatingKeys[number];

class CreditRiskRating {
    applicant_id: string = '';
    is_dirty: boolean = false;
    fillQuestionDictionaryToModel() {
        const thiz: typeof dict = this;
        creditRiskRatingKeys.forEach(<K extends CreditRiskRatingKey>(key: K) => {
            thiz[key] = dict[key];
        });
    }

}

Here I changed your for...of loop to a generic callback to forEach(), and widened this to typeof dict before doing the assignment.  Now it compiles without error.  It's annoying to have to jump through such hoops, but it's the closest we can get to having TypeScript understand our logic. If you don't want to do that you can always use type assertions like this[key] = dict[key] as never.
Playground link to code

Thank you very much for the best explanation. Just one thing, can you link microsoft/TypeScript#32693

It's right there at the top of my answer.

The type keyof CreditRiskRating is not only applicant_id but also fillQuestionDictionaryToModel. There's no real distinction between methods and properties in JS.
So eventhough CreditRiskRatingKeys is an array with only the value applicant_id, according to the type it can be an array with 'applicant_id' and/or 'fillQuestionDictionaryToModel'. Thus typeof this[key] can either be a string or a function () => void.
To solve this, you can create a new utility type PropertyOf that excludes methods:
type PropertyOf<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K
}[keyof T];

and use it as
export const CreditRiskRatingKeys: PropertyOf<CreditRiskRating>[] = [
   'applicant_id'
];

export class CreditRiskRating {
  applicant_id: string = '';


  fillQuestionDictionaryToModel() {
    for (const key of CreditRiskRatingKeys) {
      this[key] = 'test';
    }
  }
}


I've found a bug here

Updated the questions, seems that is not working!

Typescript correctly gives an error since you're assigning a string value to a boolean property. The type of this[key] is never, since there's no overlapping type for all properties of the class. What are you trying to accomplish?

I don't think that would be the problem as I already cast it to any.
Also if this is the case how this is working? this[key as keyof this] = 'test' as any;

You could use (this[key] as any) = 'test'. Note that this removes the type check.

In my real scenario there is no casting and 'any'. am looking for the best practices

TypeScript does not analyze the value types of the properties defined in your CreditRiskRatingKeys to try to figure out whether you're assigning the right value type to a given property.
One solution is to introduce a Property type that restricts the value types of the listed properties:
export type Property<T, U> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U ? K : never
}[keyof T];

export const CreditRiskRatingKeys: Property<CreditRiskRating, string>[] = [
   'applicant_id'
] as const;

export class CreditRiskRating {
  applicant_id: string = '';

  fillQuestionDictionaryToModel() {
    let f = this[CreditRiskRatingKeys[0]];

    for (const key of CreditRiskRatingKeys) {
      this[key] = 'test';
    }
  }
}


Playground link

How do you solve this case? Playground

Updated the questions, seems that is not working!

Your question is a moving target. In its current form, you're requesting for a type safe way to assign a string to what is possibly a boolean property, which doesn't make sense.

Thanks for your consideration. updated the question. hopefully now is clear!
